# unnest & scalar table function in Enterprise postgres

Tags: postgresql, plsql, oracle11g, postgresql-9.4, enterprisedb

The below is the snippet where I pass a cursor as input paramter in Oracle. 
And Im trying to convert the same to EntepriseDB.

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNCTION_1
                                                       (
                                                           p_source IN SYS_REFCURSOR
                                                       )
    is
    TYPE row_ntt
    IS
        TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
        v_rows row_ntt;
    begin
       ---            
        LOOP
            FETCH p_source BULK COLLECT
            INTO  v_rows LIMIT 1000
            ;

            FOR i IN 1 .. v_rows.COUNT
            LOOP
                -- Will do something here
            END LOOP;
            EXIT    WHEN p_source%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

it's called in the below way in Oracle:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TABLE ( function_1(CURSOR(select col1 from tbl)));
```

Now after migration

I changed like below

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNCTION_1
                                                       (
                                                           p_source IN SYS_REFCURSOR
                                                       )
    is
    TYPE row_ntt
    IS
        TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
        v_rows row_ntt;
    begin
       ---            
       select unnest(p_source) into v_rows; 

            FOR i IN 1 .. v_rows.COUNT
            LOOP
                -- Will do something here
            END LOOP;

    END;
```

Im calling in the below way in EntepriseDB/Postgresql

```
 SELECT
      *
    FROM
      TABLE (function_1(ARRAY(
          SELECT
             col1 from table)));
```

Im getting below error at assigning the value to v_rows.

```
ERROR:  cannot assign non-table type to a table
```

Please help me in making unnest as table type so that it inserts into v_rows. or else if there is a way I can use sysrefcursor in EnterpriseDB is also fine. Please let me know how to call in ENtepriseDB when sysrefcursor is used. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know what EnterpriseDB gives you, but both functions you show are Oracle functions. I don't see what has been migrated, except that `unnest` function is used in the second. Anyway, If you want to run  Oracle's `select from TABLE()`  like query in Postgres, here's an example you may refer.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I got the answer by changing v_rows as `v_rows text[]` and make `unnest` as `array` like `select array from (Select unnest(...))`, basically I made table type as array. by the way, you missed adding the reference link.